# No module named 'requests', requests shows it is installed

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

Could not locate the requests module, I have install the pip requests. I have uninstalled and reinstalled with no change. "The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead" I Imported ipyKernel with no change.

[image: No module named 'requests']

[image: It shows requests under modules but when I run the script, I received this error "moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'"]

[image: List of versions installed]

Comment: Are you using virtual-environment or default interpreter? or where did you install the `request` package?

Comment: I installed it on my windows through the terminal and also in visual studio code in the terminal.

Comment: now im receiving this error: Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_avx2.dll or mkl_def.dll. when I run py, help(), and 'modules'.